# Linq to XML Find a an attribute and return seperate attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
```

```
<aliasSection>
    <aliases>
        <clear />
        <add
            name="MAIN"
            server="JAG8MTO\SQLEXPRESS"
            database="RMain"
            trustedConnection="false" />            
        <add
            name="DEMO"
            server="JAG8MTO\SQLEXPRESS"
            database="RDemo"
            trustedConnection="false" />            
    </aliases>
</aliasSection>
```

In the above xml doc I need to search for an alias name then return the server and database attributes.

This is my first time working with xml docs and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around it.

So far I have this, I can find the aliases section but I'm at a loss have to proceed from here.

```
 public void Read(string fileName)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

        foreach (XElement el in doc.Root.Elements())
        {
            foreach (XAttribute attr in el.Attributes())

                if (attr.ToString() == "aliases")
                {
                    foreach (XElement element in el.Elements())
                        listBox1.Items.Add(element.Name + " " + element.Value);
                    foreach (XAttribute attrib in el.Attributes())
                        listBox1.Items.Add(attrib.Value);
                }

        }

    }
```

Comment: `aliases` is element, not attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aliases` is element, not attribute

```
var document = XDocument.Load(fileName);

var data = 
    document.Descendants("aliases") // Select all <aliases> elements
            .SelectMany(alias => alias.Elements("add")) // select all <add> elements
            .Select(add => new 
                    {
                        Name = add.Attribute("name").Value
                        Server = add.Attribute("server").Value
                    })
            .ToList();

listBox1.Items.AddRange(data);
```

`data` will contain selected values of all `<add>` elements.

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {item.Name}, Server: {item.Server}");
}
```

Comment: How would I check to see what the name is then return the server value? For example if the name = DEMO then return the server value for DEMO

Comment: @PaulWalker, instead of selecting only name you can select all required values in anonymous(or predefined) type

Comment: this is exactly what I'm trying to do... thank you so much for your help. Do you know of any good resources to learn this?

Comment: [LINQ to XML (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml)

Answer (score 1):

```
   // Load the xml into XElement 
   XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("F:\\db.xml",LoadOptions.None);

   // Search through descendants and 
   // find one with name as MAIN
   XElement result = doc.Descendants("add")
  .FirstOrDefault(y => y.Attribute("name") != null &&
                     y.Attribute("name").Value == "MAIN");

    // Get the values if valid element is found  
    if(result != null)
    {
      string server = (result.Attribute("server") != null) ?  result.Attribute("server").Value : string.Empty;
      string database = (result.Attribute("database") != null) ?  result.Attribute("database").Value : string.Empty;
    }
```